# Making an equivalence in Java

Tags: java, equivalence

As you will probably see from my code I'm quite new with this. I am trying to write a simple program to retrieve the friends of one person. Here is my code:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String friends;

    public Person(String aName) {
        name = aName;
        friends = "";
    }

    public String getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void addFriend(Person friend) {
        friends = friends + " " + friend.name; 
    }

    public void unfriend(Person nonFriend) {
        friends = friends.replace(" " + nonFriend.name, "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person dana = new Person("Dana");
        Person gina = new Person("Gina");
        Person john = new Person("John");

        dana.addFriend(gina);
        dana.addFriend(john);
        john.addFriend(gina);
        john.addFriend(dana);
        john.unfriend(dana);

        System.out.println("Dana's friends are: " + dana.getFriends());
        System.out.println("Gina's friends are: " + gina.getFriends());
        System.out.println("John's friends are: " + john.getFriends());
    }
}
```

Everything works, but I do not know how to create a method that will say:
If Gina is both Dana's and John's friend then clearly Gina's friends will be Dana and John. I know that I can add two lines there `gina.addFriend(dana)` and `gina.addFriend(john)`, to accomplish the same result, but I would like to know what will the method be for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a String for 'friends' but a List.

Comment: Are you aware of different data structures?

Comment: First things first: store the list of friends as a `List`, not as a concatenated string. (Or, since one person should only appear once, a `Set`.) The next step is that `a.addFriend(b);` should modify the friend sets of both `a` and `b`, and similarly with unfriending.

Comment: It is not safe to "unfriend" with `Replace`, because multiple person can have the same names

Comment: @Kilanny In this case names are probably unique, but if you have friends called "Jo" and "Jonathan", unfriending "Jo" might leave you with a new friend: "nathan".

Comment: Actually, a Set would be more appropriate: you don't want to be friend twice with the same person, and the friends have no order.

Comment: @JBNizet most likely, but the chance of only one person on earth having the name "John" is not that big

Comment: Not a problem if it's a Set<Person>

Comment: Everyone thanks for your answers. @biziclop I understand the concept that you are describing but I do not know exactly how to write it:-). Do I have to make a set for every person involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make `friends` an `ArrayList<Friend>`.

```
private ArrayList<Friend> friends;
```

This has several advantages, including being easier to use and storing the `Person`s themselves rather than just their names.

Then, change the `addFriend` method to go in both directions:

```
public void addFriend(Person friend) {
    friends.add(friend);
    friend.friends.add(this);
}
```

In this way, friendships will automatically go back and forth.  You should also change `unfriend`:

```
public void unFriend(Person friend) {
    friends.remove(friend);
    friend.friends.remove(this);
}
```

EDIT: as per a comment above, a set would actually be better, as it can only have one of each value.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Set, and add a unique Id to person to get around the problem of multiple people having the same name.

Your class will then look like:

```
public class Person
{
    private final String personId;
    private final String name;
    private final Set<Person> friends;

     public Person(String personId, String name) {
        super();
        this.personId = personId;
        this.name = name;
        this.friends = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

     public void addFriend(Person friend) {
         if(friend != null && !friends.contains(friend)) {
             this.friends.add(friend);
             // Optional : if it is a two-way relationship that doesn't need approving etc
             friend.addFriend(this);
         }
     }

     public void unfriend(Person nonFriend)
     {
         if(nonFriend != null && friends.contains(nonFriend)) {
             this.friends.remove(nonFriend);
             // Optional : if it is a two-way relationship that doesn't need approving etc
             nonFriend.unfriend(this);
         }
     }

     public Set<Person> getFriends()
     {
         return friends;
     }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person dana = new Person("D001", "Dana");
        Person gina = new Person("G001", "Gina");
        Person john = new Person("J001", "John");


        dana.addFriend(gina);
        dana.addFriend(john);
        john.addFriend(gina);
        john.addFriend(dana);
        john.unfriend(dana);



        System.out.println("Dana's friends are: "+dana.getFriends());
        System.out.println("Gina's friends are: "+gina.getFriends());
        System.out.println("John's friends are: "+john.getFriends());

    }


    // Equals and Hashcode are very important when using 'contains' and other Set-based methods

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((personId == null) ? 0 : personId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (personId == null) {
            if (other.personId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!personId.equals(other.personId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use an arrayList of persons/friends instead of one string.

```
ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>;
```

you add friends by typing:

```
public void addFriend(Person newFriend){ 
    friends.add(newFriend);
    newFriend.friends.add(this);
}
```

you delete friends by typing:

```
public void unfriend(Person noFriend){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.friends.size(); i++){
        if(this.friends.get(i).name.equals(noFriend.name){
            this.friends.delete(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < noFriend.friends.size(); i++){
        if(noFriend.friends.get(i).name.equals(this.name){
            noFriend.friends.delete(i);
        }
    }
}
```

to show the whole list of friends:

```
public void showFriends(){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.friends.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(this.friends.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am sure that this works perfectly but I haven't reached yet the level so that I can understand all that you wrote here. As I am just learning this concepts I would just want to ask again if there is a method that I can write this, without changing the Sting into an arrayList. A method that will say if Gina is John's friend then Gina will be John's friend.Thanks again!

Comment: if(anyName1.friends.contains(anyName2)&&!anyName2.friends.contains(anyName1)){
    anyName2.friends = anyName2.friends +""+anyName.name
}
You would have do call this every time you add a friend to someones list.